# jquery send hidden input via ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, post

I wm trying to send data via ajax

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    // Get all the forms elements and their values in one step
    var values = $(this).serialize();

});
```

This form only has `hidden input tags with values` like this

```
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$post_by_user.'" name="posted_by" />
  <input type="hidden" value="like" name="like_button" />
```

how to send the form on click `div="send"` without submit form? is there is another method?

another method I am triyng

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#like").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
       var post_info = $("#post_info :input").serialize();
    $.post("like.php", post_info).done(function(data) {
      $("#like").html(data);
    }).fail(function() {
      //alert("Error");
    })
  })
})
</script>
```

Comment: You mean `serialize()`?  Serialize works with hidden fields.  Did you try it and see?

Comment: yeah serialize the hidden inputs and send via post

Comment: Right, `serialize()` already does that.  So what is the issue?

Comment: see my question update, somehow it's not sending data do backend

Comment: What is the result of `$("#post_info :input").serialize();` ?

Comment: I have 2 inputs `<input type="hidden" value="'.$post_by_user.'" name="posted_by" />
  <input type="hidden" value="like" name="like_button" />`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  If you console log the results of the serialize on that selector, what is the result?

Comment: it shows blank, how can I add a console log after done function?  `console.log("#post_info);` ?

Comment: `post_id=5601928&posted_by=user` so that means it's right? so maybe it's the data base that it's not saving data?

Comment: Ohh yeah I think it's not jquery problem I run the backend post file and i have I undefined variable

Comment: I have like `<div id="like"> <input type="hidden">  <button icon></div>` also the inputs is inside `#post_info` form

Comment: somehow I am trying to insert the vars into db without jquery and I am not getting any error now, it's just only not saving into db but I think it's a db query problem.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize like this and use ajax

```
     var frm1 = $(document.myForm);
     var jdata = JSON.stringify(frm1.serializeArray());
      $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "Your URL",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ sdata: jdata}),
                    success: function (result) {
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.serialize()` prepares a data string that is suitable for `GET` requests. You should use `$.serializeArray()` if you want to use a `POST` request, like shown below:

```js
$('#frm1').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var vals = $(this).serializeArray();  // prepare a data object
    $.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", vals)
     .done(function(data) {  // display the server response:
        console.log("posted:",JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm1">
  Here is the form with invisible fields<br>
  <input type="hidden" value="one" name="var1" />
  <input type="hidden" value="two" name="var2" />
  <input type="hidden" value="three" name="var3" />
  <input type="submit" value="send in background" id="btn">
</form>
```

Comment: I only just noticed that I answered a four year old question ... :D - sorry for creating so much noise! :D :D